# Event handling for an array of objects

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, events, controls

I have an array of controls that I have populated with labels, and comboboxes.

3 columns, 10 rows. First column is all labels, the remaining columns are combo boxes.

I was wondering how to handle the event when a user changes one of the combo boxes?

Regards

J

Comment: The Array is created when the form is intialized

Comment: Show us your code / research efforts, and specifically what's not working - the solution is easily found on any question involving events and dynamic controls.

Comment: Here, did your research for ya. Cheers!

Comment: @BigJ, please add your comment info to your post, so that it is part of the question .... BTW, the first two lines of your post are just "fluff", the actual useful part that relates to your question is the 3rd line.